# How to list files accessed by a newly process

Tags: shell

I believe that a few years ago I worked with a shell command like

```
SOMECOMMAND php index.php
```

giving me a list of all files that were accessed during that process, e.g.

```
index.php
config.php
some system internals
...
```

I do not want the list of an ongoing process (since my script lives only for milliseconds), but explicitely the chronological order of file accesses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strace` is the command tracing all system calls of a running executable.

You can filter the strace log to filter only with a file is opened:

```
strace php index.php 2>&1 | grep ^open
```

`2>&1` is needed for `grep` because `strace` is by default logging to `stderr`.

Comment: Another way to filter: `strace -e open php …` (see manual page for `strace`). No need to bother with redirections.